# jhipster/spring keycloak integration - setting custom redirect_uri

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

I have a spring / jhipster application, with a button to login to keycloak. When I click the login button, it brings me to keycloak, and the URL would look something like

```
https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclient&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/oidc
```

So in the above, I want to change the `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/oidc` to something else.

So I added the below code in src/main/java/../config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("myclient")
                .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("mysecret"))
                .scopes("resource:read")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .redirectUris("https://new-url-I-want.com");
    }

}
```

But even with the above change, the redirect_uri doesn't change at all. Anyone know why this is?

---

And more information on why I made those changes:

With OIDC's authorization code flow, the service provider (in this case my website) provides the identity provider (Keycloak) with the URI to redirect the user back to after successful authentication. However, per the Spring docs, "With the default configuration, while the Authorization Code Flow is technically allowed, it is not completely configured":
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2-boot-authorization-server-authorization-code-grant

The docs go on to state that "OAuth2 Boot does not support configuring a redirect URI as a property — say, alongside client-id and client-secret." so,

"To add a redirect URI, you need to specify the client by using either `InMemoryClientDetailsService` or `JdbcClientDetailsService`":
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html5/#registering-a-redirect-uri-with-the-client

Comment: There is a property which changes the redirect uri (but I think you need that redirect uri for successful login). 
In case you really need/want to change the redirect uri you can try adding the 
property to src/main/resources/config/application.yml


spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oidc.redirect-uri

Comment: The official boot documenation can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-security-oauth2-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the follwing lines inside the method `SecurityConfiguration.configure`

```
       .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/url_to_redirect")
```

That is:

```
   public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { ...

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) { ... }

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
      .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .and()
        .oauth2Login()
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/url_to_redirect")  // <--- HERE
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another redirect uri by adding the following property and src/main/resources/config/application.yml

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: web_app
            client-secret: web_app
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/my-custom-redirect
```

Furthermore you have to configure the custom redirect uri for the oauth2 login in SecurityConfiguration as follows

```
...
.and()
   .oauth2Login()
       .redirectionEndpoint()
        .baseUri("/my-custom-redirect")
    .and()
.and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
...
```

Comment: Hey just getting back to this. Do I have to put anything extra in the "redirect-uri" above? I try it with making it use the URL of my site, and after logging into keycloak, it redirects me back to the main page of my site, but nothing seems to happen. I then changed it to "h t tp s://mysite.net/my-appended-url/login/oauth2/code/oidc", but it can't find that route (even though its supposed to redirect back to there), so I'll try messing with that URI a bit more

Comment: I will try to check again but basically that was my configuration I used.

Comment: thanks @atomfrede. And the reason I am in need of this redirect, is because my app is on a URL that a bunch of other apps share, and this main url (ie. "myurl.com") is the load balancer. And then my app lives on "myurl.com/myapp". But after I login to keycloak, it is bringing me to the "myurl.com/login/oauth..." instead of "myurl.com/myapp/login/oauth.."